# How to display all logic 'IF' in stored procedure mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with 1 parameter but linked to 3 tables, I want to display all of the table with one parameter with this query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`brambang`@`%` PROCEDURE `Read_discount_campaign`(IN Insert_ID INT(10)
    )
proc:
BEGIN   
DECLARE is_insert_id INT(10);
DECLARE param_1_message TEXT;
SET @is_insert_id = Insert_ID;

SELECT CONVERT( CONCAT('Maaf, ID discount_campaign tidak bisa \'0\'') USING UTF8) INTO param_1_message;

IF (Insert_ID = 0) THEN
        SELECT param_1_message AS message;
        LEAVE proc;
            END IF;

IF (Insert_ID != 0) THEN
    SELECT * FROM discount_campaigns where 
    id = @is_insert_id;
        END IF;

IF (Insert_ID != 0) THEN
    SELECT * FROM discount_campaign_advanced where
    discount_campaign_id = @is_insert_id;
        END IF;
        
IF (Insert_ID != 0) THEN
    SELECT dcp.discount_campaign_id, CASE  WHEN dcp.active = 0 
    THEN dcp.product_id ELSE pc.category_id END as discount_campaign_product
    FROM discount_campaign_product dcp JOIN product_categories pc
    ON dcp.product_id = pc.product_id
    WHERE dcp.discount_campaign_id = Insert_ID;
        END IF;
END
```

After I run this, the output was only from this query (last IF logic)

```
IF (Insert_ID != 0) THEN
        SELECT dcp.discount_campaign_id, CASE  WHEN dcp.active = 0 
        THEN dcp.product_id ELSE pc.category_id END as discount_campaign_product
        FROM discount_campaign_product dcp JOIN product_categories pc
        ON dcp.product_id = pc.product_id
        WHERE dcp.discount_campaign_id = Insert_ID;
            END IF;
```

Instead what I want is it displays all of the logic not only the last one, how to combine all of this logic so the output was from all of the logic, not only from the last logic, is it use cross join?

Comment: 3 SELECT produces 3 rowsets. So the procedure returns a collection which consists from 3 rowsets. But you get data from one rowset only (those which is "on the top of collection"). For to access another rowsets you must iterate over this collection. PS. You use `DECLARE is_insert_id INT(10);` but this variable is not used anywhere in the procedure. What's the aim?

Comment: so how to produce on 3 rowsets with iterate over? oh yes sorry will deleted this variable

Comment: *how to produce on 3 rowsets with iterate over?* This depends on your client's programming code - I don't know, read accessing methods manuals. *will deleted this variable* I'd recommend do backward, and use it instead of UDV `@is_insert_id`.